# How to generate a DirectShow filter from live555 source files

Tags: c#, c++, directshow, live555

After some time I've been able to compile the live555 source codes following this [Post](http://tdistler.com/2011/05/14/live555-compiling-with-vs2008).
Once compiled I have a bunch of *.obj files but no .ax or .dll file. I'm new in C++, and was trying to generate a DirectShow filter or a dll to use it from C#, so far I've been unable to do so.

How can I generate a Directshow filter or a dll from these files? I'm mainly interested in using the Rtspclient.

Comment: Did you get a .lib by any chance? The build configuration could be set up to generate a static library. If that's the case you'll have to modify the build script to generate a dynamic link library (should be relatively painless)

Comment: No, Mike I didn't get any .lib

Comment: If you're not getting any _executable code_ (.exe, .dll, .lib, .ax etc) out of the build process then something is not right with the build. I have a hard time believing that the build script doesn't generate any executable code.

Comment: I'm going to check the building process again. So far I only get one .obj for each .cpp element.

Comment: The .obj files contain binary code that is usually further linked into an executable file or library to be used by 3rd party code. You could still include the .obj files (and their respective headers) in your project but it's a bit more work. Is the project supposed to produce a DS filter? Or just some code that you'd like to use with a DS filter that you'd be building?

Comment: I'm building an app to visualize a video stream from a network camera. I hoped that these source codes would generate a DS filter or at least a .dll, for me to use form C#.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Tom Distler? After all he authored the original post and perhaps might be able to help with your issue directly.

Comment: No , I haven't contacted him. That is going to be my next step. thx.